# General question on choosing an Assembly language based on my goal

Tags: computer-architecture

So I know assembly is so big and it seems learning assembly is like learning high level programming, you don't need to learn them all, you can learn couple and this will be enough.

The thing is with high-level language it is easier to grasp and implement in your life. But I am having hard time with assembly, I learned ARM at university, but I am not sure which version it was. And, it wasn't practical in real life. Also, it was too primitive. It doesn't even help me read other assemblies. Because when i read other assembly, I am lost seeing too many new commands that I have never seen before.

But I want to learn a language where I can add it to my code or make stand-alone version out of it easily like C++ or C# for Windows, so basically a practical language, also a language with live community and not an abandoned one.
i learned some programming languages and they are useless for me like CLIPS, ADA and Prolog.

So what are the useful and practical assembly languages out there to learn for windows. Is FAsm a good start? Also note that I do not know what I want to do with it, I will learn it them when I get good command of it I will decide, I may use it for images, or AI project or anyother use where my path will lead. I already know C++ (i use it for UE4 and AI code implementations), C# (desktop/web) app and java (desktop).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Programming questions are off-topic, here, but can be asked on [so]. Actually, I'm slightly confused by your question, since assembly language tends to be CPU-specific so "Which one should I learn?" is basically "Which computer will you be programming?" You also seem generally confused about the differences between assembly languages and high-level languages.

Comment: this question is off-topic there  as well and i had similar question removed by overflow! 2- I know the difference between assembly and high level, it was explain as part of my degree, I was just trying to explain my point but English is not my native language so it's a bit difficult to be concise . and because Assembly is CPU specific I don't know which one to learn hence my confusion. and I did mention twice the OS I am after which is windows, whether 64 or 86 is irrelevant for me hence i did not mention. finally feel free to remove it if it's off topic

Comment: [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better place to ask. By the way, your object is not at all clear to me. As once a university student, you should be able to pick up any assembly quick should need arise. You should better explain why assembly languages can be useful and practical to you when you raise your question. For example, your ideal job requires that. Or your code is way too slow for your current job. Otherwise, what you have learned in university is enough (you can review that). I am voting for unclearness.

Answer (score 1):

There is very, very little need for assembler. For is very rarely need for inline assembly - for example, I have some code somewhere that calculates (a * b) / c for unsigned 64 bit integers where a * b overflows.

And asking "which assembler should I learn" - if you ever need assembler, then that's the one you need to learn. Any other assembler is useless.

The only case where you *really* need to use assembler is at the extreme ends: When you are creating a virtual machine, you need to understand the extremely rarely used instructions to do this safely. If you create codecs, or encryption software, where you have very small amounts of code using up huge amounts of CPU time, that's where you may need assembler. But you don't need to know just assembler. You need to know and understand CPU instructions that have been created exactly for these purposes. You are in a highly specialised area there.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux diehard, I suggest [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) which is both classical (for Linux) and still actively strong.

For ARM programmer, I suggest [GNU assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler).

Comment: Thanks, but do you recommend NASM over MASM and FASM for windows?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't know if this is good advice or not but please note that programming questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Okay thanks, but I have seen similar questions on here, This is not technical question, so it's off topic on stackoverflow because they are all about code errors and S.E as well so if Computer Science is off topic then where is it not off-topic to post it there? I studied assembly at Computer science course at Uni!!!

Comment: @ma1169 Perhaps it's not on-topic anywhere. Programming is studied as a part of CS degrees but we don't cover it here because, if we did, we'd get overrun by programming questions. And most of it is covered by Stack Overflow.

Comment: "I studied assembly at Computer science course at Uni!!!" I am feeling (everybody fills his/her version here).